# How to use Primefaces menu

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm a beginner in JSF, I want to create a menu using primfaces 3.5 tag, I used this code:

```
<h:form>
  <p:menu>
    <p:menuitem value="Computers" url="#"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Clothes" url="#"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Gaming" url="#"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Books" url="#"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Jewellery and Watches" url="#"/>
  </p:menu>
```

When I run the server nothing is showing.

Comment: Is this the entirety of your view code, as in this is everything you have in the .xhtml file?

Comment: @fareed Don't correct code in a question unless OP states that they didn't copy everything. Malformed XML could be one of the problems.

Comment: @Sumurai8 not closing an xtml <h:form> tag will result in an error which will not render the page. However, you are right, OP must state first. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem, it was a web.xml problem, i forgot to add the xhtml extension